# I need to know how to fill an arrays indexes with other arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods, for-loop

i want to create an array of 5 indexes, which will have an index with another whole array in each one. each array within the 5 index will need to be as many indexes as follows (10, 100,1000,10000) but i dont know how to fill an array like this inside of my for loop ,that is typically used with an array, without it running into infinity, because where i have 
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++),
i cant use the x variable in here;
int[x<--(syntax error)] array = {ten = new int[arraySize], hundred = new int[arraySize], thousand = new int[arraySize], tenthousand = new int[arraySize],
without it telling me there is a syntax error . i don't know what to do.

all this code is part of a method of its own class as well if that helps understand better.

public int ArrayArray(int arraySize, int randomNumber) {

```
    arraySizes = arraySize;

    for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        size = 0;

    Random gen = new Random(randomNumber);  

    int[]ten;
    ten = new int[arraySize];
    int[] hundred;
    hundred = new int[arraySize];
    int[]thousand;
    thousand = new int[arraySize];
    int[]tenThousand;
    tenThousand = new int[arraySize];

    int[] array = {ten[x] = gen.nextInt(10), hundred[x] = gen.nextInt(100), 
            thousand[x] = gen.nextInt(1000), tenThousand[x] = gen.nextInt(10000)};

     return array[];
    }
```

this changes my question a little i think ive got it after having worked on it. does this look like it will return what i want it to do?  im going to have a driver that i will call this method with a given array size and a given number of random integers.

Comment: can you edit your post and put the code that you are having problems with?

Comment: Yeah. Post your code, I'm having difficulty processing your question.

Comment: the return of this method doesnt work btw as well

Comment: is the return the only thing you are having trouble on at this point?

Comment: yes im not sure what i should return

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return and array your function try this:

```
public int[][] ArrayArray(int arraySize, int randomNumber) {
    Random gen = new Random(randomNumber);
     int[]ten= new int[10];
     int[] hundred= new int[100];
     int[]thousand= new int[1000];
     int[]tenThousand= new int[10000];     
     int[][] array = {ten,hundred,thousand,tenthousand};
    return array;
}
```

notice it is `int[][]` and not `int[]`. this is because the array you are trying to return a two dimensional array not just a single dimensional array.

let me know how this works.

Comment: i got rid of the arraySize parameter becuase i can just say in the method what the size of a given array is going to be ie. int[]ten;
  ten = new int[10];
do i still need to create the multiarray?

Comment: yea, otherwise you'll get a bunch of arrays of the same size. but what are you trying to do with those arrays? are you trying to fill them up with random numbers?

Comment: Im doing sorting methods in class right now and my assignment is to take these particular arrays and arrange each of them in five different ways with sorting methods (descending order, increasing order, and 3 random generated lists). im not sure im going about it the right way.

Comment: "For this part, you will compare the performance of the sorting algorithms on different lists.  You 
should output the number of comparisons each sorting algorithm makes for each list.  Generate 
the following 5 lists in 4 sizes (10, 100, 1,000, & 10,000 elements):
1. Increasing order (1, 2, 3, . . . )
2. Reverse order (10,000/1000/100/10 . . . .1)
3. Three randomly generated lists (make sure they are different!)"

Comment: is that all the directions your assignment gives you? do they give you a sorting algorithm?

Comment: i thought it would be easier if i actually made one method with an array of the five different array types i need, and then calling this method, as well as casting the sort class into the driver, so the driver would ue that sort method on all of the arrays at once.

Comment: So you want a method that just returns to you an array of arrays? And then you want to use this two dimensional array for the 5 different lists you have to generate? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, by using the different sort methods in my sorting class such as bubble sort, quick sort, etc, to do so.

Comment: ok well I don't know what your sorting classes look like, but I updated my answer. that function should do it. your gonna have to modify it slightly to fit your needs (aka using the random number generator) Let me know how it goes.

Comment: thats ok i can handle the sorting class, but how do i take 
the int[][] array = {ten,hundred,thousand,tenThousand}; and randomize it. you cannot convert from int[] to int.

Comment: you want to set the arrays ten, hundred, thousand and ten thousand to have random integers stored in them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create array of arrays then multi dimensional array is the way to go.

```
int arraySize = 10;

int[]ten = new int[arraySize];
int[] hundred = new int[arraySize];
int[]thousand = new int[arraySize];
int[]tenThousand = new int[arraySize];

int[][] array = new int[4][arraySize];

array[0] = ten;
array[1] = hundred;
array[2] = thousand;
array[3] = tenThousand;
```

Also passing around a 2-dimensional array is same as arrays. Eg.

```
public static int hello(int[][] pass) {
    return pass;
}
```